# Appium test not going any further after Splash Screen

Tags: ruby, mobile, automation, appium

I'm hoping someone can help.
I am testing the Three App where correct behavior should be once the app launches, a splash screen is shown for a few seconds, then a login page is presented.

I'm trying to automate this using appium but once the automated test opens the splash screen, the test ends.
I am shown this error message:

```
NoSuchElementError: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters. at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.findElOrEls (C:\Users\zminhas\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-android-driver\lib\commands\find.js:75:11)
```

Here is my env.rb code:

```
require "appium_lib"
require "pry"


opts = {
         caps: {
           deviceName: :Anyname,
           platformName: :Android,
           app: 'C:\Users\zminhas\Desktop\three_app_automation\features\support\biometrics.apk',
           appPackage: "com.hutchison3g.planet3",
           appActivity: ".SplashScreenActivity",
           noReset: true
         },
         appium_lib: {
           #wait_timeout: 30

         }
       }
Appium::Driver.new(opts, true).start_driver
Appium.promote_appium_methods Object
```

And my hooks.rb code:

```
Before do
    $driver.start_driver    
end

After do
    $driver.driver_quit
end
```

Here is the full results screen:

```
$ cucumber
*** WARNING: You must use ANSICON 1.31 or higher (https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/) to get coloured output on Windows
Feature: All external URLs work as expected within the More Tab

2019-11-11 12:08:13 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] Selenium::WebDriver::Error::TimeOutError is deprecated. Use Selenium::WebDriver::Error::TimeoutError (ensure the driver supports W3C WebDriver specification) instead.
  Scenario: test                        # features/more_tab.feature:3
    Given I see the enter number screen # features/step_definitions/more_tab_steps.rb:1
      An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters. (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError)
      NoSuchElementError: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
          at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.findElOrEls (C:\Users\zminhas\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-android-driver\lib\commands\find.js:75:11)
      ./features/step_definitions/more_tab_steps.rb:2:in `"I see the enter number screen"'
      features/more_tab.feature:4:in `Given I see the enter number screen'

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/more_tab.feature:3 # Scenario: test

1 scenario (1 failed)
1 step (1 failed)
0m14.888s
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: I have tried using 'sleep' function but still no joy

Answer (score 0):

Try with following capabilities

```
           deviceName: :Anyname,
           platformName: :Android,
           automation_name: :uiautomator2,
           app: 'C:\Users\zminhas\Desktop\three_app_automation\features\support\biometrics.apk',
           appPackage: "com.hutchison3g.planet3",
           appActivity: ".SplashScreenActivity",
           noReset: true
```

Comment: Hi @Mani
Thank you for your suggestion.
Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: please post your appium logs to further debug this issue

Comment: Hi @Mani
The log is too long to fit in this comments section so please view it via this google drive link:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Vulw9j_ru4DVzFzOu5QawNU54REHDbR5yN4UAclNats/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you

Comment: Hi @Mani
I was able to find a solution.
I added ```appWaitActivity``` to env.rb.
This allowed the second page to load.
Thank you for your time and all the best

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue when an app was given to me in an interview. but after 2 days  I was able to find the solution to the issue related to Splash Screen being stuck and not going to the second screen using script/appium but manually it was working fine.
The issue is something related to INTENT Activity
Solution:
I added some extra line of code to script/capabilities to appium and it worked fine.
Try using these lines in capabilities for the apps that have splash screen issue.

```
capabilities.setCapability("androidCoverage","com.my.Pkg/com.my.Pkg.instrumentation.MyInstrumentation");
capabilities.setCapability("androidCoverageEndIntent","com.example.pkg.END_EMMA");
capabilities.setCapability("intentAction","android.intent.action.MAIN");
capabilities.setCapability("intentCategory","android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
capabilities.setCapability("intentFlags","0x10200000");
```

Please Let me know if it worked for you also?