# Appium Server GUI: How to add a Desired Capability criterion to wait for splash screen to disappear before the AUT starts?

Tags: appium, splash-screen, desktop, inspector

I am new to desktop UI automation and am currently using Appium with WinAppDriver, coding in C# on the Visual Studio 2022 Pro IDE.

I have a splash screen that launches the app. This splash screen lasts for about 4-5 seconds.
So, when I launch Appium Server GUI to inspect elements on my app, Appium registers the splash screen first, so I can't get past it.

How can I tell Appium desktop inspector to ignore the splash screen?

I tried the following, but they have no solution that I can use:

https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/issues/1481
[Appium test not going any further after Splash Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58801205/appium-test-not-going-any-further-after-splash-screen)

I'd appreciate a way to set this in the Appium desktop inspector UI, as a setting for ignoring splash screen.

Answer (score 0):

DesiredCapabilities iCloudCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

**iCloudCapabilities.setCapability("ms:waitForAppLaunch",15);**

iCloudCapabilities.setCapability("app", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Apple\Internet Services\iCloud.exe");